# Canvas not drawing text?

Tags: java, android, canvas, view, draw

I want to display some text on Screen when the user clicks a `button` with `canvas` in `android studio`. I  have been looking at many posts and videos of how to do that. The problem, when I tried their code, when I clicked my button, nothing showed up. Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

**Here is my `Java` class:**

```
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button drawCanvas = findViewById(R.id.draw_canvas_button);

    drawCanvas.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Paint paint = new Paint();
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
            paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            paint.setTextSize(20f);
            canvas.drawText("My Text", 10f, 15f, paint);

        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: you not showing the canvas, see this
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html

Comment: @Mohamd Al-Najjar I cannot resolve my problem. I see i have to use some sort of BitMap, but I still cant find my error.

Comment: you can display the bitmap on ImageView

Comment: Oops! Bitmap refers to ImageView, witch is not what I need. Never mind  bitmap. My code still dosent work. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you have to use a method called `onDraw` by importing `View`.

```
import android.view.View;

public class myClass extends View{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


}
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    //Where you put the code
}
```